# Server sent unexpected return value (502 Bad Gateway) in response to COPY request

Tags: eclipse, spring, svn, repository, subclipse

I'm using Spring Tool Suite 3.1.0 with the latest Subclipse installed over it.
Committing and updating worked just fine, until I received the following message while trying to commit:

Server sent unexpected return value (502 Bad Gateway) in response to COPY request for 'some filename'

The url of my repository is: https://megiforge.pl/svn/zpi2012

Now I tried to google the answer to my problem, but all the solutions seem to mention changing Apache server configuration, and I can't wrap my head around finding the corresponding files in Subclipse config.

The only thing that could cause this was me moving a file from one folder to another, because that's the only difference between this and my previous commits. Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If the solution is to fix your Apache server configuration, and all of the archived discussion on this problem says that it is, then there is nothing you can do in your client configuration.  This is a change that needs to be made on the server.  It sounds like it happens when the server has a reverse proxy or SSL accelerator configured in front of the Apache server.

One example here:  http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-03/0549.shtml

Comment: For anyone from the future stumbling upon this answer: the problem is, you can't rename or move your files if you're using https connection. You have to make new ones and paste the contents into them.

Comment: It's a useful approximation that's likely to solve the problem in many cases.

Comment: So funny. I just encountered the same problem on a commit command. Googling it to find a solution, I arrived to this answer on StackOverflow that points to my original post on the SVN mailing lists some 13 years ago. I can't stop laughing !